# Receiving a Review Request from IEEE Transactions as a Ph.D. Student

Tags: peer-review

I'm a Ph.D. student and trying my best to publish papers in IEEE Transactions.
I don't have any published work in the journal, except the one published in a journal in mdpi, and the one that has got a revision request from one of IEEE Transactions journals and been submitted again.

Recently, I got a Review Request from the other IEEE Transactions journal. As I looked at the paper, I felt confident in reviewing the paper and accepted the request. I think I did a good job in review.

However, I still don't understand the reason they sent me a review request, since the only publication I have is one in a moderate journal. The one is not even close to the topic of the reviewed paper.

Do they just randomly send the review request? Or, can a paper under review process make the authors eligible for reviewer?